# A current PhD applicant in a dilemma between current lab and other programs

Tags: phd, masters, application, recommendation-letter

Some of my backgrounds: Currently a master's student in a good but not top school. Now in a research group that could have been more productive. I am applying for PhD programs in this round of application (applying in 2020 and entering in 2021).

My current professor invited me to join his lab as a PhD student. However, I am quite done with computational chemistry and I am indeed interested in doing other topics in the future. I want to talk with my advisor about this but I don't want to be completely insecure with my options. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just because someone invites you to continue at their school does not mean they will not support you in applying elsewhere, especially if the other places are higher rated. This is a common confusion for students and gets asked a couple times a year on this site. If they did not refuse to write you a letter then you should say you appreciate the offer and then go ahead and apply widely as you had planned.

Comment: You are not turning down, you are waiting to see what the full choice set entails.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you be as open and honest with your current supervisor as you can. No surprises, no evasion. Tell him your list of schools. Tell him you want to aim as high as you possibly can. From your current A+ school, possibly to an A++ school.

I have known some students in your position. A student who excels under a professor makes the prof look very good. If that student goes on to one of the very tip-top schools after working with the prof, the prof's reputation grows. Maybe he is sad to see you go, but he should also be glad to see somebody he taught go on to Big Things.